# Need Help Finding Power Supply Information

Tags: power-supply, dell-precision

My apologies in advance if this is not the correct community for this type of question.

Situation:

I am using a Dell Precision Tower Workstation 5810 and would like to install an Nvidia Quadro P5000. However, I am having trouble finding the specs on the installed PSU. I tried various features on Dell's support site but I can't find what I am looking for. The information on the computer, even using the specific service tag, gives, at best, the required input. I need to know the output capability to ensure that it can support the new GPU; ideally in addition to the current one (Nvidia Quadro K620).

Currently, there are two unused 6-pin power connectors. Based on what I have found online so far, I will have to use either a 2x6-to-8 adaptor (according to Nvidia) or a 6-to-8 adaptor (according to "GPU and CPU power connections" on overclock.net) since the new GPU requires 180W and is equipped with an single 8-pin receptacle. According to Nvidia, if I use a 2x6-to-8 adaptor, I need to make sure that the PSU can handle providing output at 18A. overclock.net simply stated that pin 2 needs to be wired (which appears to be the case).

Image of PSU label to be uploaded soon.

I have already checked that there is an open PCIe3x16 slot (per Nvidia's instructions).

Questions:

Are there any other potential issues or less than ideal situations I need to check for? Regardless, does anyone know where I can find the PSU specifications?

The instructions also say that there should be "enough" space between the GPU and other components. What is considered "enough"?

---

Apparently, you need 10 reputation to post a picture. Sorry.

Comment: The definition of "enough" in the context of a determiner is **as much or as many as required**.  This means "enough" space, in the context of a GPU fitting in the case, is that there is enough space for **it to fit in the case**

Answer (score 0):

The PSU specifications are listed in [the manual](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/precision-t5810-workstation/precision_t5810_om_pub-v2/working-on-your-computer?guid=guid-9ccd6d90-c1d1-427f-9e77-d4f83f3ad2b6&lang=en-us).

The manual states at Technical Specifications:

> **Table 30. Power**
>   **Feature Specification**
>   Voltage 100 VAC to 240 VAC
>   Wattage
>   Tower 5810 685 / 425 W (input voltage of 100 VAC – 240 VAC)
>   Maximum heat dissipation
>   685 W 2750.5 BTU/Hr
>   425 W 1706.5 BTU/Hr
>   **NOTE:** Heat dissipation is calculated by using the power supply wattage rating.
>   Coin-cell battery 3 V CR2032 lithium coin cell

Enough space between other components must ensure the heat from the fan is not congested because its nearly touching another card. The more space the better, but if one PCI slot is free between the card and the next, that's usually enough.

Comment: I saw that already. Perhaps I just don't know how to interpret it. I need to find out information such as whether or not it can output 18A.

Comment: Your post did not mention you already found the wattage, still you asked for it. Anyway, the wattage is all you need to be concerned about. If the PSU has the right connectors, and it does in your case, then the only other question is, if there's enough wattage.

Comment: My bad then. I should have stated that I already found the table in the manual. My concern about "enough" space is that the GPU comes less than a 1/4" from touching some other components (which, as a complete noob, I can't identify). However, with regards to judging based on PCI slots (following your 1-free-slot rule), there should be enough space. Although the P5000 is a double-height GPU.